# IndexError: list index out of range (web scraper using python)

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am doing web-scraping previously it was working fine but suddenly it showing error: list index out of range at  for following code

```
casos = html_soup.find_all('tr') 

    value=[]                           
        for i in range(0,len(casos)):
          l=casos[i].get_text().split('\n')[1:11]
          if l[0]=='Country,Other':
            value.append(i)

    for i in range(1,value[1]): 
      l=casos[i].get_text().split('\n')[1:11]
```

i have tried to change the range of list but it not working

Comment: Without any idea what you are scraping, what do you expect anyone here to do?

Comment: what line causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error might be in 2nd loop at value[1]
At the first index there might be no value there. Check printing value[1]

Comment: yes, the error is at value[1]. when i print it same error